# Use object with toXML method inside a JAXB-annotated object?

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, pojo

I'm a web services developer.  At my employer, they have a very rich data model that I probably can't change too much.

Nearly all of the objects have had the ability to render themselves as XML via a toXML() method.  Think of them as hash maps where we don't know the full set of fields until runtime.

I'm trying to leverage JAXB wherever possible, so some of my web services objects are regular POJOs annotated as you'd expect.  However, I'd like to add one of our older objects inside the JAXB-annotated POJO and call its toXML().

For example:

```
@XmlRootElement
class Metadata {
    @XmlAttribute String serviceVersion;
    @XmlAttribute String applicationVersion;
    @XmlElement User user; // this is our object with it's own toXML method
}
```

Ideally, I'd like to see the marshaled result as:

```
<metadata serviceVersion="5.1" applicationVersion="12.1">
    <user id="bmauter" firstname="Brian"/>
</metadata>
```

I've looked into extending XmlAdapter, but the output is something like:

```
<metadata serviceVersion="5.1" applicationVersion="12.1">
    <user>&lt;user id=&quot;bmauter&quot; firstname=&quot;Brian&quot;/&gt;</user>
</metadata>
```

Then I thought I read somewhere to make the XmlAdapter convert my object into an org.w3c.dom.Element.  I decided to try that, but it blows up because "JAXB can't handle interfaces".

How can I embed such an object in a regular JAXB-annotated POJO?

Thanks!

UPDATE:  Here's the actual example I'm trying to fix.  (Updated again to show that the set of field names aren't known until runtime.)

```
import java.util.HashMap;

import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAttribute;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlAdapter;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlJavaTypeAdapter;

@XmlRootElement
public class Metadata {
    @XmlAttribute String serviceVersion = "5.1";
    @XmlAttribute String applicationVersion = "12.1";
    @XmlElement @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(UserXmlAdapter.class) User user = new User();

    static class User extends Row {
        public User() {
            tablename = "users";
            fields.put( "id", "bmauter" );
            fields.put( "firstname", "Brian" );
        }
    }

    static class Row {
        String tablename = null;
        HashMap<String, Object> fields = new HashMap<String, Object>();

        public String toXML() {
            StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
            result.append( "<" ).append( tablename );
            for( String fieldName : fields.keySet() ) {
                result.append( " " ).append( fieldName ).append( "=\"" ).append( fields.get( fieldName ) ).append( "\"" );
            }
            result.append( "/>" ); 
            return result.toString();
        }
    }

    static class UserXmlAdapter extends XmlAdapter<String, User> {
        @Override public User unmarshal( String v ) throws Exception { return null; }
        @Override public String marshal( User user ) throws Exception { return user.toXML(); }
    }

    public static void main( final String[] args ) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance( Metadata.class );
        context.createMarshaller().marshal( new Metadata(), System.out );
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried declaring the user as `@XmlValue String user;`? You could store the User as a non-jaxb field and return its XML in the getUser() method.

Comment: One can only have one of those @XmlValue annotations for a given parent element. Even then it still escapes the text though. 99.999% of the time it does what you want. I'm just a little surprised that we have no way of sticking externally-generated XML in the middle of a jaxb object.

Answer (score 1):

When you have the following

```
@XmlRootElement
class Metadata {
    @XmlAttribute String serviceVersion;
    @XmlAttribute String applicationVersion;
    @XmlElement User user; // this is our object with it's own toXML method
}
```

The `User` object will be rendered within the XML for the `Metadata` object based on its mappings.  There isn't anything special you need to do.

Comment: Thanks, but I want the result of the toXML to be in the JAXB output.  BTW, I'm humbled you answered.

Comment: @bmauter - I wouldn't recommend that approach.  If your `toXML` method simply returns a `String` it isn't going to work well with other marshal outputs such as `XMLStreamWriter`, `Node`, etc.  If the `toXML` method is based on the JAXB mappings your going to get the same result anyways.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know the full set of fields until runtime.  There's nothing to annotate.  Is there something else I could return that would fit in?  What if it returned JAXBElement?  How would I build that out programmatically?